# Can I use a Pebble with CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, pebble

I can't seem to find an answer to this question using my favourite search engine.

Is it possible to use a Pebble watch with an Android phone running CyanogenMod, assuming that it is possible to install the Pebble App via an APK file?

I'm wondering whether anyone has got this working, or knows that it definitely won't work because CyanogenMod does not include 'features' which are in the normal Android operating system it's expecting to be there.

I can provide more information about which specific phone and CM version if this is necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question will likely vary from device to device because CyanogenMod focuses their efforts on popular devices, and older phones don't get as much love and attention.

From my research, success with the Pebble also then varies per device (source [1](http://www.reddit.com/r/pebble/comments/1fl47b/connectivity_issues_cyanogenmod_101/), [2](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/smartwatch-compatibility-with-cyanogen.1679/), [3](http://www.androidcentral.com/cyanogenmod-11-m3-builds-now-rolling-out)). Some people have had success and never encounter a single issue. Others have connectivity issues (not connecting, connection drops, etc.) or battery draining problems.

Suggested solutions are:

1. Flash a different Kernel
2. Try any other aftermarket Android project ([AOKP](http://aokp.co/), [PacMan](http://www.pac-rom.com/#Home), [SlimRoms](http://www.slimroms.net/), [Paranoid](http://download.paranoidandroid.co/))

**Conclusion:** You will probably need to flash the ROM(s) and test it yourself. ALWAYS BACKUP FIRST. Copy that backup to an external device, just in case. It more than likely that it will work without any hiccups. If for whatever reason you're not satisfied, then you can always restore to your backup.

**Sidenote:** your statement that "CyanogenMod does not include 'features' which are in the normal Android operating system" is incorrect. From CyanogenMod's [About page](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/about):

> Based on the Android Open Source Project, CyanogenMod is designed to increase performance and reliability over Android-based ROMs released by vendors and carriers such as Google, T-Mobile, HTC, etc.

They use the same Android source code as any other vendor, except that they actually improve and enhance the Android user experience. They do not remove standard features and services. I think of CM as what Android *should* be, but thats debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Late response: You won't even need the official Pebble app for that. I successfully initialized my *Pebble Time Steel* using the FOSS [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) app<sup>**1**</sup> (CM11 here). This way you won't even need to create an account. Only drawback of this solution: access to the Pebble app store isn't implemented in the app (at least currently not). But if you downloaded `.pbw`/`.pbz` files, you can install and manage them with this app. Even firmware updates are possible.

**TL;DR:** Yes, you can use a Pebble watch with CyanogenMod :)

PS: Related: [Smartwatch compatibility](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/141150/16575)

---

<sup>**1:** also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge)</sup>

Comment: PS: It's running fine with CM12.1 as well (same device was updated a while ago). And Gadgetbridge evolves :) More details in my article on [Smartwatches and privacy – contradiction in terms?](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/smartwatch-privacy)